# Nuxt JS Laravel echo PrivateChannel not receiving any data

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, socket.io, pusher

I'm using Laravel 8, as an API, and a Nuxt JS front-end using the tymon auth package and v5 of the auth module. I've set up a private channel, and am trying to receive data but nothing is coming through, public channels work fine, I'm using the pusher replacement option and the websockets integration.

What am I missing?

**app\Events\SendFetchBeamSignal.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendFetchBeamSignal implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The user
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'hello' => 'hello'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user.'.$this->user->id);
    }
}
```

**routes/channels.php**

```php
Broadcast::channel('user.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

My JS:

```js
this.$echo.private('user.1').listen('SendFetchBeamSignal', (data) => {
  console.log('received')
  console.log(data)
})
```

And for now, I'm broadcasting a notification via a route...

```php
Route::get('/broadcast', function () {
    broadcast(new SendFetchBeamSignal(User::find(1)));
});
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors about subscribing to the private channel in your browser console? When the app works for public channels but fails for private channels then to issue is likely to be related to the authentication flow. This is detailed in laravel at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

Comment: Took me quite a bit longer to figure this out, but the resolution here is to manually set the auth header and change the auth endpoint.